# Error when mapping in ggmap with API key (403 Forbidden)

Tags: r, ggplot2, gis, ggmap

I normally use `ggmap` to plot points on a simple city map. When doing this today I came up on a new error that forbids me to use the function `get_map()`

```
        #get API key @ https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/get-api-key
    key<-"AIzaSyCYgKKt2fn7Crt-V6Hnc5aw5lSfy7XLQ-Y"
    register_google(key = key)

atw<- get_map(location=c(-88.68,42.14), zoom=10, scale=2)
```

I am not sure where the problem is. Ive tried a new API key but no luck. Any input?

The error reads:

> cannot open URL
>   'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=42.14,-88.68&zoom=10&size=640x640&scale=2&maptype=terrain&language=en-EN&key=AIzaSyCYgKKt2fn7Crt-V6Hnc5aw5lSfy7XLQ-Y':
>   HTTP status was '403 Forbidden'Error in download.file(url, destfile =
>   destfile, quiet = !messaging, mode = "wb") :    cannot open URL
>   'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=42.14,-88.68&zoom=10&size=640x640&scale=2&maptype=terrain&language=en-EN&key=AIzaSyCYgKKt2fn7Crt-V6Hnc5aw5lSfy7XLQ-Y'

Answer (score 6):

*updated: 2018-12-01 for ggmap 2.7.904 and current Google Cloud API*

## Problem

Your API key is

- either **not valid** (wrongly typed) / **not enabled for billing** (most probable cause) or
- there are some connection/proxy issues.

Check out this [step-by-step tutorial on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52617929/9406040).

## Solution

To check what the issue is type `geocode("Houston", output = "all")` and look at the error message.

#### 1. Wrong API key

```
> geocode("Houston", output = "all")
$error_message
[1] "The provided API key is invalid."

$results
list()

$status
[1] "REQUEST_DENIED"
```

This means you have provided an API key that is not recognized by Google. Maybe mistyped, maybe miscopied? Sometimes there are weird issues, so **generate a new API key** in the Google Console and **try again**.

#### 2. API key not enabled for geocoding

```
> geocode("Houston", output = "all")
$`error_message`
[1] "This API project is not authorized to use this API."

$results
list()

$`status`
[1] "REQUEST_DENIED"
```

This means your API key is valid, but you have not allowed usage of this specific API. Remember: Google has an API for every little type of request (static maps, directions, geocoding, ...). Therefore, you need to **go to your Google Console and enable this API key for the right APIs**, in this case **Geocoding**.

## Working output with all APIs enabled

```
> ggmap(get_map("Houston"))
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 2):

If you're API key is working you can also use `library(googleway)` to plot interactive maps

```
library(googleway)

## you can use separate API keys for different APIs
set_key( "GOOGLE_API_KEY", api = "geocode")
set_key( "GOOGLE_MAP_KEY", api = "map")

## you can view the keys you have with
google_keys()

google_map( location = c(52, 0), zoom = 6 )
```

[image]

```
## add a marker by geocoding an address
res <- google_geocode("Buckingham Palace")
loc <- geocode_coordinates( res )

google_map() %>%
  add_markers(data = loc)
```

[image]