# get_map not passing the API key (HTTP status was '403 Forbidden')

Tags: r, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ggmap

I have been facing this issue in the `get_map()` function (`ggmap` library) in R.

My code was running without the need to specify an API key (for `source = "google"`) for several months. However, the code stopped working a couple of weeks back. I understood that Google has made the API key mandatory (or maybe they allowed a certain no of calls without the api key which I exhausted).

However, even after specifying the API key (obtained from Google Cloud Platform) my code continued behaving the same way. I even contacted Google Cloud Support, but they said there was nothing wrong with the API key per se and they were able to invoke the map at their end.

I suspect the `get_map()` function is not passing the `api_key` while invoking the map from Google. Any pointers towards resolution would be appreciated.

Below is the reproducible code (that is failing).

```
library(ggmap)

lat <- c(4,41)  # India lat boundaries
lon <- c(68,99) # India long boundaries
center = c(mean(lat), mean(lon))

map <- get_map(location = c(lon = mean(lon), 
                            lat = mean(lat)),
               api_key = <my api key>,
               zoom = 6,
               maptype = "terrain",
               source = "google",
               messaging = TRUE
)
```

And below is the error message in R (note the API key is not getting passed)

```
trying URL 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=22.5,83.5&zoom=6&size=640x640&scale=2&maptype=terrain&language=en-EN&sensor=false'
Error in download.file(url, destfile = tmp, quiet = !messaging, mode = "wb") : 
  cannot open URL 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=22.5,83.5&zoom=6&size=640x640&scale=2&maptype=terrain&language=en-EN&sensor=false'
In addition: Warning message:
In download.file(url, destfile = tmp, quiet = !messaging, mode = "wb") :
  cannot open URL 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=22.5,83.5&zoom=6&size=640x640&scale=2&maptype=terrain&language=en-EN&sensor=false': HTTP status was '403 Forbidden'
```

Comment: Thanks @SymbolixAU. I will check this out subsequently. For now, my problem got resolved by using get_googlemap instead of get_map. Seems get_map is not designed to accept the api_key when the source is google. get_map uses the api_key only when the source is cloudmade.

Answer (score 17):

You need to use `register_google(key = "..."`) in every new session of R. Using `api_key =`  inside the `get_map()` call does not work.

---

*updated: 2018-12-24 for ggmap 2.7.904 and current Google Cloud API*

## Step-by-Step Tutorial

### 1. Update to newest version of ggmap

```
require(devtools)
devtools::install_github("dkahle/ggmap", ref = "tidyup")
```

### 2. Activate your Google API key for all APIs in the Google Cloud Console

- [Link for more info on how to get an API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key)
- [Direct Link to Google Cloud Platform Console](https://cloud.google.com/console/google/maps-apis/overview)
- [Direct Link to Google Maps API Pricing Information](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/sheet/)
- APIs you need: **Maps Static** and **Geocoding**
- Enable **billing** in the general settings.

[image]

[image]

### 3. Load ggmap and register key

```
library(ggmap)
register_google(key = "...")     # copied directly from Google Console via 'copy' button
```

### 4. Plot default map

```
ggmap(get_googlemap())
```

[image: Houston]

### 5. Plot with location name (Geocoding)

```
ggmap(get_map("Hannover, Germany"))
```

> If you get an error here (e.g., Forbidden 403) you most probably have not activated your key for the right APIs. [Tutorial to troubleshoot geocoding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52617264/9406040)

[image: Hannover]

### 6. Plot with longitude and latitude

```
ggmap(get_map(location=c(16.3738,48.2082), zoom=13, scale=2))
```

[image: 3]

Comment: Hyy, I get the following error for `ggmap(get_googlemap())`  
"Source : https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=29.763284,-95.363271&zoom=10&size=640x640&scale=2&maptype=terrain&key=xxx
Error in aperm.default(map, c(2, 1, 3)) : 
  invalid first argument, must be an array
In addition: Warning message:
In get_googlemap() : HTTP 400 Bad Request" .. 
What do I do?

Answer (score 6):

Just to add to Roman Abashin's answer (I can't comment, unfortunately): As per '?get_map()', the 'api_key =' argument doesn't work for Google maps. You'll need to use the 'register_google()' function, but as of 03/10/18, it's only in the development version of ggmap, which you can get like so:

```
devtools::install_github("dkahle/ggmap", ref = "tidyup")
```

Then you'll also need to enable billing on your Google account, though the first 100,000 maps you use each month should be free, see here: https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/sheet/ for details.

(tips drawn from here: https://github.com/dkahle/ggmap/issues/51)

Comment: Absolutely right, thank you!  Here is my [attempt at a rough step-by-step tutorial](https://github.com/dkahle/ggmap/issues/51#issuecomment-425719270).

Comment: @ErnestScribbler I expanded my answer to also include the tutorial

Answer (score 4):

I don't know the direct resolution to the `ggmap` issue, but if you're happy to work with an interactive map rather than a static one you can use my `googelway` library

```
library(googleway)

set_key("GOOGLE_MAP_KEY")

lat <- c(4,41) #India lat boundaries
lon <- c(68,99) #India long boundaries
center = c(mean(lat), mean(lon))

google_map(location = center, zoom = 6)
```

[image]

Comment: I started to have the same issue as before. Nothing shows up in the R viewer and this time even opening it in a browser doesn't help. Just wanted to let you know. Cheers for all the help that I got from your packages throughout these years.

Comment: @Masoud - is there an error in the javascript console ( in the browser, right click (outside the map), select 'inspect', and go to the 'console' tab)

Comment: Don't have my laptop with me, will check and report back.

Comment: @Masoud odd that was required, but glad it's now working again

Answer (score 2):

Just adding to @Roman's response, here's the code that worked for me:

```
if(!requireNamespace("devtools")) install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("dkahle/ggmap", ref = "tidyup")
library(ggmap)
register_google(key = "your_API_key") 
usa<- get_googlemap(location='united states', zoom=4,maptype = "hybrid")
```

For more information you could refer to the library page on github: [here](https://github.com/dkahle/ggmap) 
Hopefully it helps!