# problems with reverse geocoding

Tags: r, json

I'm trying to query several coordinates through the revgeocode command of the ggmap package, but at the time of running my code tells me that it is not possible to connect to the API url.

I'm trying to understand:

1. How to place the API key inside the code so that the query can be generated?
2. Why does it tell me that I have already exceeded the number of consultations if I have not made one?

Below is part of the code:

```
ll <- cbind(Longitud, Latitud)
LL_1 <- as.matrix(ll)
DirR <- rep(0, nrow(LL_1))

for (j in 1:nrow(LL_1)){
  DirR[j]<- revgeocode(LL_1[j,])

}
```

Comment: Read https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-and-billing and https://github.com/dkahle/ggmap/issues/227#ref-issue-359659441. So you might want to enable billing and switch to the well documented [`googleway`](https://github.com/SymbolixAU/googleway) package.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R get\_map not passing the api key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52565472/r-get-map-not-passing-the-api-key)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to upgrade `ggmap` to `version 2.7.903` from Github and register your Google Maps API key. There is a tutorial [under this link](https://github.com/dkahle/ggmap/issues/51).

> 1. How to place the API key inside the code so that the query can be generated?

You have to `register_google(key = "...")` in every new R session before you execute any calls to the API.

> 2. Why does it tell me that I have already exceeded the number of consultations if I have not made one?

If you do not register a billing-enabled Google Maps API key, you share the quota with all the requests of your geographical region.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, apparently that side already works.

But now another mistake marks me
1: In revgeocode(mat[j, ]) :
  reverse geocode failed - bad location? location = "-99.23125"reverse geocode failed - bad location? location = "19.447889"
Given this I do not understand what the problem is because the coordinates are getting as requested by the command (Longitude / Latitude)

Comment: Try `revgeocode(c(-99.23125, 19.447889), output = "all")`. If you get the error message `"This API project is not authorized to use this API."` you have to enable this type of lookup in your Google Maps API / billing.

Comment: Hello again
I have managed to pass the barrier of the download but now another question arises ...
How can I manage to separate the address thrown in different columns so that each column is left with a specific data
I tried this but I can not make it to be in different columns.
´S1v$sep <- strsplit(S1v$DireccionGM, split = ",")

do.call(rbind.data.frame, strsplit(DireccionGM, ",|."))´