# How to pass a google API key to get_maps?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I am trying to use `get_map` and I presume google now requires to access the API using a key since the code in the documentation doesn't work

```
get_map(location = "texas", zoom = 6, source = "stamen")
```

> Error in download.file(url, destfile = tmp, quiet = !messaging, mode
>   = "wb") :    cannot open URL 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=texas&zoom=6&size=640x640&scale=2&maptype=terrain&sensor=false'
>   In addition: Warning message: In download.file(url, destfile = tmp,
>   quiet = !messaging, mode = "wb") :   cannot open URL
>   'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=texas&zoom=6&size=640x640&scale=2&maptype=terrain&sensor=false':
>   HTTP status was '403 Forbidden'

Suppose my key is XXX, I thought this would work:

```
get_map(location = "texas", zoom = 6, source = "stamen", api_key = 'XXX')
```

However, I get the same error as before. I suppose I am passing the key incorrectly since the new error message doesn't show `XXX` anywhere in the URL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `register_google(key = "...")` in every new session of R. Using api_key = inside the `get_map()` call does not work.

from: [R get_map not passing the api key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52565472/r-get-map-not-passing-the-api-key?rq=1)

Comment: what package is `register_google()`? can't find it using `??register_google`...

Comment: it's from ggmap, the documentation doesn't look up to date, but I could find it on the github repository for ggmap:
https://github.com/dkahle/ggmap/blob/master/R/register_google.R

Comment: Are you using `ggmap_2.6.1`? I get `Error: 'register_google' is not an exported object from 'namespace:ggmap'`

Comment: the CRAN version is still not up to date with google's new gmap API, from what I read. Try the following command to update it: `devtools::install_github("dkahle/ggmap", ref = "tidyup")`

Comment: @automa7 I had to install digest and glue manually in order for that to work but it did!