# Accessing latitude and longitude coordinates in Geocode

Tags: r

I am trying to plot points for countries on a map (so I can eventually make a network style map) of Argentine exports. However, I don't know how to convert the country names to latitude and longitude. I tried using geocode, but it says NA for the latitude and longitude values and I get a "geocode failed with status REQUEST_DENIED, location = "USA"" error. Is it an error with my API? Do I need to put my API key in the geocode statement? Or how does it know to access the geocode? I think this is my error, but I am not sure. Is there an easy way to fix this? Or a different package I can use?

```
library(maps)
library(ggmap)
library(ggplot2)
new <- data_frame(city = c("France", "Brazil", "Uruguay")) %>%
    mutate_geocode(city)
```

Comment: Yes you do need to use the API key, not in every geocode statement but in every R session

Answer (score 0):

This is a recent issue I think where Google tightened control over use of their geocoding service due to excessive traffic, now requiring API registration. This github [page](https://github.com/dkahle/ggmap/issues/213#issuecomment-429674805) and this [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52565472/get-map-not-passing-the-api-key-http-status-was-403-forbidden/52617929#52617929) question seem to have solutions for getting it working again.

Alternatively, you can use dsk as a secondary source for geocode requests, though I don't know how accurate the figures are.

```
new <- data_frame(city = c("France", "Brazil", "Uruguay")) %>%
    mutate_geocode(city, source = "dsk")

    city lon lat
1  France   2  46
2  Brazil -55 -10
3 Uruguay -56 -33
```

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you have google maps API key already,

```
library(ggmap)
register_google(key = " ")
```

then test if you can plot

```
ggmap(get_map("France", "Brazil", "Uruguay"))
```

If you cant its probably related to your API key not being active or wrong

Comment: When I try to test it with this it says "Error in register_google(key = "...") : could not find function "register_google"". I don't know why it isn't recognizing the register_google function. Do you I need to add a package?

Comment: Restart R Studio and run `sessionInfo()` this should give you the version of the `ggmap` loaded. Add it to your question pls