# Error in ggmap: get_googlemap doesn't work because Forbidden (HTTP 403)

Tags: r, api, google-maps, ggmap

I am trying to create a map file with ggmap but there is this persistent error of Forbidden (HTTP 403). I am using an API key, but that doesn't seem to work either.

Here is the code:

`library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap)
set_key("...API-key...")
dm <- get_map(location="Spain", zoom=6)`

Then this is the message I receive:

`Error in get_googlemap(center = location, zoom = zoom, maptype = maptype, : Forbidden (HTTP 403).`

The code used to work at home, but now I'm living on campus. Could IP address affect this too?

SOLVED I had already got an API key. However, as has been pointed out by @Roman, I need a billing-enabled account to make it work. It didn't cost money, but you do need to give your credit card.

Comment: There are numerous questions with the **same error code** here on SO. It means you have not registered a valid, billing-enabled Google Maps API key via `register_google()` in the newest version of `ggmap`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is something wrong with the ggmap and mapview packages in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52743142/is-something-wrong-with-the-ggmap-and-mapview-packages-in-r)