# Displaying and Animated google heat map?

Tags: r, google-maps, heatmap, googleway

how can i Displaying and Animated google heat map
i have already used this code

```
swf1 <- read.csv("D:/modilingfinel/swf1.csv",header=TRUE) 
head(swf1) 
set.seed(20170417) 
df <- swf1 df$weight <- sample(1:10, size = nrow(df), replace = T) 
google_map(key = "API_Key", data = df) %>% add_heatmap(lon = "Lon", lat = 
"Lat", 
weight = "weight", option_radius = 0.001, legend = T)
```

but i didnt work 
any help, thank you

when i try run the whole code i got this

```
       swf1 <- read.csv("D:/modilingfinel/swf1.csv",header=TRUE)
       head(swf1)
       swf1 <- make_bbox(lon = swf1$Lon, lat = swf1$Lat, f = .1)
       library(googleway); google_map(key = 
       "API_KEY") %>% add_markers( data = swf1, lon = "Lon", lat = "Lat") 
        set.seed(20170417)
        swf1 <- swf1
        swf1$weight <- sample(1:10, size = nrow(swf1), replace = T)

        google_map(key = "API_KEY", data = swf1)%>% add_markers( data = swf1, 
        lon = "Lon", lat = "Lat") %>%
        add_heatmap(data = swf1, lon = "Lon", lat = "Lat", weight = "weight",
                    option_radius = 0.001, legend = T)
```

[image]

Comment: What does it give you? How 'doesn't it work' ?

Comment: @SymbolixAU i edit the question please look, thank you...

Comment: It could be your coordinates are too far apart to correctly aggregate into clusters. Try increasing the `option_radius` value to 1, or 10, or 100 etc and see what it gives.

Comment: @SymbolixAU it did work i try 5 and 10 it goes perfectly, i have a question in this locations i have bad and good locations i want to simply them with 2coler how can i do that ? also i want to chance the base-map to black coler how can i do that? and one last thing i want to do one map and it have button so if i click it it shows me the locations and another one for heat-map in one map instated of 2 maps?

Comment: have a look at `?map_styles` for styling the map. Then see [my vignette](http://symbolixau.github.io/googleway/articles/googleway-vignette.html) for all examples and documentation.

Comment: @SymbolixAU i read everything in Package ‘googleway’ i did many things it was very helpful, but in the servile things i have asked you before i couldn't understands how to do it, im new to R i have start learning it about month ago and i learned so many things becoz of you

Comment: Thanks, and it's good you've taken the time to read the docs. Therefore, for each of your specific questions could you please open a new question, and include code and data in your questions so I can clearly see what you've already tried, and what you're trying to do?

Comment: @SymbolixAU i have been trying all day long, and i closed the R without saving the codes i have been trying ....... can you give me a codes of my questions , thank u so much