# Registering API key in R for ggmap

Tags: r, ggmap

I'm trying to retrieve a map of the UK with the package `ggmap` in R and believe I'm having trouble due to Google's relatively new API terms and conditions from this year.

```
install.packages("ggplot2")
library("ggplot2")
install.packages("devtools")
library("devtools")
devtools::install_github("dkahle/ggmap")
library(ggmap)
```

I'm attempting to register my key below for my R session, but when I use my API key I receive the error code in R `object not found`. I have not included my key below.

```
register_google(key)
```

I'm getting this error for the map:

> Forbidden (HTTP 403)

for the code directly below:

```
map_UK <- get_map(location = "United Kingdom", zoom = 4)
```

I've given billing credentials to Google API and enabled all of the Google Maps features. I would appreciate any help with this.

Comment: I've had similar issues with `ggmap` and found using `googleway` instead to be a much better experience https://github.com/SymbolixAU/googleway

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51481913/5977215

Comment: Did you surround your key with quotation marks like `register_google("ABC123")`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get\_map not passing the api key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52565472/get-map-not-passing-the-api-key)